# Is it a good idea to always set file.encoding system property in Java?

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

I think it is a good idea to always set `file.encoding` system property in Java application.

Suppose I *do not* set `file.encoding`. It means that Java will use a platform-dependent default charset (e.g. in `String.getBytes`), which makes the whole application platform-dependent.

If we set `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`, for example, we guarantee that such calls as `String.getBytes` work the same in any platform.

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't necessarily make sense. If you want to read files that have not been created by your own application, on any platform, you'd better leave the file encoding as it is by default, because that's what you'll need to be able to read these files.

And if you read files created by your own applications, or by applications which use a well-known and specified file encoding, then you should simply use this encoding when instantiating your IO readers and writers.

For methods such as `String.getBytes()` just don't use them, and use `String.getBytes(Charset)` instead if you want to use a specific encoding instead of the platform's default one.

Comment: What if I cannot guarantee that String.getBytes is never used in the application code base?

Comment: If you can't have this guarantee, can you have the guarantee that setting the platform file encoding to something other than the actual platform encoding won't cause even bigger bugs? The default value is the best default value you can have.

Comment: I do not know. That is what I am trying to understand. You say that setting the platform encoding may cause bugs if the application reads files created by others. Ok, I see it now.

Comment: When you say files not created by your own application, there are some caveats here.  These would be files created by other applications running on the same platform.  Files coming from other platforms wouldn't benefit in anyway.  It's also assuming those files were created using the "platform default" and not specifically using UTF-8 (or any other.. though why anyone would intentionally use anything other than UTF-8 would be a mystery to me).

Answer (score 0):

Conditionally yes.  As JB mentioned, using the "platform default" may occasionally help when reading files generated by other local applications (or other remote ones on the same platform if you have a homogeneous server farm).

So, take the choice with care, but in general I'd say do it.  The advice to always create your own readers isn't always possible.  I believe in general that most things generating files that use extended characters end up using UTF-8 for it.

In the end, because many files are dependent on the choices made outside your control, it's going to come down to testing and customization, but I feel far more comfortable suggesting that you start with UTF-8 and downgrade as necessary than the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

It is not generally a good idea to set the `file.encoding` System-Property, because this is not a supported configuration option in Java.

That means it may or may not work. *Not working* can mean [Exceptions](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7181721). To be precise problems of the sort "It works on Java 1.6, it works on Java 1.7 on Windows, BUT it does not work on Java 1.7 on Linux anymore."

The reason behind that is given [here](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4163515):

> The "file.encoding" property is not required by the J2SE
>   platform specification; it's an internal detail of Sun's implementations and
>   should not be examined or modified by user code.  It's also intended to be
>   read-only; it's technically impossible to support the setting of this property
>   to arbitrary values on the command line or at any other time during program
>   execution.
>
> The preferred way to change the default encoding used by the VM and
>   the runtime system is to change the locale of the underlying platform
>   before starting your Java program.